# Checkmate with Pawn and King

Tags: chess

Is it possible to checkmate an opponent with a king and a pawn without the pawn promoting to a queen or rook? I've heard that it is possible, but I don't know what the strategy is.

Comment: Are there any other pieces on the board? The answer depends on whether you mean just a king and pawn vs king

Comment: So king and pawn vs king ends in stalemate if you can't promote?

Comment: If there's no other pieces involved - yes.

Comment: Stalemate, yes, unless the pawn is captured, then it's a draw due to insufficient material.

Comment: but you can still win on time...

Comment: Possibly, it's been several years since i played, however, if it's a rook pawn, it may be declared a draw.

Comment: @Anonymous You can't win on time if there is not enough material left for a mate (e.g. K+N vs K). I'm not quite sure about an unpromotable pawn, you should ask on chess.SE if you want to be sure. In most cases you will draw by threefold repetition or stalemate anyway, if your opponent has more than a couple of seconds left.

Comment: I mean the pawn team win on time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The checkmated king is in one of his corners with one of his bishops on the same rank right beside him (blocking him). The checkmating pawn is in front of the bishop (checkmating the king) with the winning king two squares in front of the checkmated king on the same file protecting his pawn and blocking the checkmated king's move forward.  Of course there can be no piece available to capture the checkmating pawn. [image]

Comment: What's to block the bishop, adjacent to the king, from simply taking the pawn?

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Because the pawn is in front of the bishop.  Bishops move/attack diagonally.

Comment: Ah, I misread the pawn being in front of the king, okay.  (I re-read it 5 times, too ><)

Comment: @PaulEvans It's a really good answer :-)

Comment: Sorry I was new and I do not have enough rep.

Comment: Since this is a question about puzzles, rather than a puzzle being posed (although I suppose some could take it as such), do we really need the spoiler tag?

Comment: @jhabbott  And thanks for the board - tried to make one but didn't work.. but white and black can't be in this position with a checkmate:( Remember - the checkmated king has to be in one of *his* corners.  The white king is in one of *black's* corners so the black pawn isn't checking.

Comment: What if white was on top playing down and black was on the bottom playing upwards? That's how I intended the board - can you explain more as I don't get how this isn't possible?

Comment: @jhabbott ok, yes that'd work. But why make it confusing?

Comment: Again, you added a picture :-D

Comment: Why is it more confusing? Is there a convention in chess board diagrams that you always display it as if white is playing from the bottom upwards or something like that? I'm not a chess player so I don't know. Anyway if you want to change the image feel free - I made it using this: http://www.apronus.com/chess/wbeditor.php

Comment: @jhabbott Yes, that's the convention but never mind - thanks :)

Comment: What about if the king is at b3 and black's last move was cxb2 or axb2?